# Getting empty object form svg image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

The below piece of code works fine in my firefox browser and the same file when i run in the chrome i am facing an issue

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

</head>
<body>
 <embed src='first.svg' type='image/svg+xml' id='test'/>

 <script>


$(document).ready(function() {
  var embed = document.getElementById('test');// getting undefined

    embed.addEventListener('load', function(){
         var svg = embed.getSVGDocument(); //getting null
         var pathElements = svg.getElementsByTagName('path');
         for(var i=0;i<pathElements.length;i++){
         $(pathElements[i]).bind('click', function() {
           alert($(this).attr('id'));
         });
         }
         });
   });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**ERROR**

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'getSVGDocument' on 'HTMLEmbedElement': Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

**Question:**

why this is working in firefox and not in chrome is there any specific document object should be provided for chrome.